# find conditions on input data such that a linear system has (no) feasible points

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, optimization

As a result of the apllication of Farkas' lemma I obtained the following problem:
Let $ m,n,q \in \mathbb{N} $, $ b \in \mathbb{N}^m, l \in \mathbb{N}^m $ with $ l_i \mid q$ for all $ i=1,\ldots,m $. Furthermore let $ a^{(k)} \in \mathbb{N}_0^m $ with $ \left(a^{(k)}\right)^{\top} l =q, a^{(k)} \le b $ for all $ k=1,\ldots,n $.

---

Now consider the linear system:

(1.) $ \left(a^{(k)}\right)^{\top}y \ge 0$ for all $ k=1,\ldots,n $

(2.) $b^\top y<0 $

In which cases or under which conditions, depending on the input data $b, l $ and $q$, this system has a solution $ y \in \mathbb{R}^m $? In which cases there is no solution? Is there a characterization?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I changed the problem a little bit. Now only the case with $ z=0 $ is considered.